# Complicated jQuery .hover Work

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate, mouseenter

The following code is giving me a lot of trouble.  To note, .hover changes the background image.  Firstly, how can I combine the two with .hover rather than a separate mouseenter and mouseleave?  Second, How can I make it so that while the div is shifting upwards, the background image is simultaneously fading?

```
$('div.designbox.orangehello').mouseenter(function() {
   $('div.designbox.orangehello').animate({
     top: '-=10',
   }, 55, function() {
     $(this).addClass('hover');
   });
 });

 $('div.designbox.orangehello').mouseleave(function() {
   $('div.designbox.orangehello').animate({
     top: '+=10',
   }, 55, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('hover');
   });
 });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the two using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), do this:

```
$('div.designbox.orangehello').hover(function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: '-=10' }, 55, function() {
     $(this).addClass('hover');
   });
}, function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: '+=10' }, 55, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('hover');
   });
});
```

As for the fading, you'll need to post your markup, you'll need an additional `<div>` or something containing the other background.

A few other notes, you have `{ top: '-=10', }` for your animation arguments...watch out for those trailing commas, they'll give you trouble, especially in IE.  Also, you had `$('div.designbox.orangehello')` inside, if you're animating lots of these, change this back, but if you want the current one only use `$(this)` like I have above.